# Where to download Microsoft.Expression.Interactions version 4.0.0.0 runtime version v4.0.30319?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm currently looking for :

> Microsoft.Expression.Interactions   version 4.0.0.0  runtime version
>   v4.0.30319

AND

> Microsoft.Speech  version 10.2.0.0 runtime version v2.0.50727

Can I download it or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft.Expression.Interactions is in [Microsoft Expression Blend SDK for Silverlight 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=3062) and I think that for the second one you need to download is the [Speech SDK 5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121)

Answer (score 8):

You need to install

> Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4

or

> Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4.5

And you can find that **Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll** in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries

or in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries

Comment: I can't find `Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4.5` for download anywhere.

Comment: @JoaoMilasch In fact I don't remember where I got it. But take a look here `http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/` Perhaps you have to install VS2013 or last Webplatform.  I have installed Expression Encoder 4 with SP 2, Expression Web Trial and Expression SuperPreview Trial. I hope one of this app has what you need.

Comment: It does work on my developer workstation. It doesn't on our build environment though... :( I did find Expression.Blend.SDK on Nuget... I'm experimenting with that now...

Comment: @JoaoMilasch Well try to install it within some Windows Virtual Mashine. If you need those DLLs I can upload it to some place. Just share for couple of minutes login to upload.

Comment: Oh, you are very kind Superman. However, I'm happy to inform that it won't be necessary as Expression.Blend.SDK Nuget package did it for me :). Send my best to Lois. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I've found installing this package using the NuGet package manager resolved the issue:

```
PM> Install-Package MicrosoftExpressionInteractions -Version 3.0.40218
```

Please see https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicrosoftExpressionInteractions/

Answer (score 0):

I know that the first is bundled in Nuget; always the easiest way for me.  Check for the other.